# Running an accessibility audit during Protractor E2E tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor, accessibility

I'm looking at adding automated accessibility testing to our E2E tests. The app is built in Angular and we use Cucumber, Protractor & Chai for our E2E tests. I found the [protractor-accessibility-plugin](https://github.com/angular/protractor-accessibility-plugin) and I'd like to integrate this into the project. I've installed the plugin and I've updated the protractor config to the following:

```
var path = require('path');

exports.config = {
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    specs: [path.resolve('e2e_testing', 'features', 'example.feature')],

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: 'e2e_testing/steps/*.spec.js',
        format: 'pretty'
    },
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    plugins:[
        {
            chromeA11lyDevTools: {
                treatWarningsAsFailures: true
            },
            package: 'protractor-accessibility-plugin'
        }
    ]
};
```

The page I am testing has some accessibility errors and warnings within it. My tests run but there is no indication that the accessibility audit has been performed and no report being generated. Does anyone know what I've missed here?

Comment: Could you able to figure out how to do this?